# Contributed control to the status bar not visible

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to place a control in the status bar of the workbench window. The whole process should be straight-forward, but whatever I try, the status bar contribution does not become visible.

Because I do not *own* the application but just contrinbute a plug-in to the IDE, `WorkbenchWindowAdvisor` and friends are not an option.

The extension point is this:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.status" allPopups="false">
      <control class="MyContributionItem" id="myContributionItem" />
   </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

and the `MyContributionItem` class is like this:

```java
public class MyContributionItem extends WorkbenchWindowControlContribution {
  protected Control createControl( Composite parent ) {
    Label label = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
    label.setText( "STATUS BAR!" );
    return label;
  }
}
```

What I tried so far, all without sucess (i.e. the status bar contribution does not show up):

- added `?after=org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager` to the `locationURI`
- put a breakpoint in `MyContributionItem#createControl()`, it is never reached
- target platform: Eclipse Platform SDK 3.8 or 4.4: makes no difference
- changing the `allPopups` attribute to `true`

I am quite sure that I am mising something very obvious, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
Plugin.xml

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.status">
     <toolbar
           id="org.ancit.search.web.searchbar"
           label="Search Bar">
        <control
              class="org.ancit.search.web.controlContributions.GoogleSearchControlContribution"
              id="org.ancit.search.web.controlContributions.GoogleSearchControlContribution">
        </control>
     </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Check [GoogleSearchControlContribution](https://github.com/cmalai/eclipse-utils/blob/master/org.ancit.search.web/src/org/ancit/search/web/controlContributions/GoogleSearchControlContribution.java) class on github

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, the `<toolbar>` element seems to be required for the control-contribution to show.

Comment: @ Chandrayya G K - Please provide your email. Need to talk about some RCP dev work.

Comment: @Amrit Visit my StackOverflow [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1391924/chandrayya-g-k?tab=profile). You will see my twitter handle, email etc.